# Inequality involving variable powers

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, functions

I'm trying to get an expression for $r \geq 0$ in terms of $n$ which satisfies

$$(1+\epsilon)^{r} \geq 4r^{2}\mathrm{log}(n)$$

Would it be possible to show there exists some constant $C=f(\epsilon)$ such that $r=C\mathrm{log}(n)$ satisfies the inequality? So far I've just been using graphical methods.

Answer (score 0):

We have, using that $e^x=\sum_k \frac{x^k}{k!},$

$$(1+\epsilon)^r=e^{r\log(1+\epsilon)}\ge \frac{\log^3 (1+\epsilon)}{6}r^3$$ for any $\epsilon >0.$

So, one sufficient condition that guarantee the inequality is

$$\frac{\log^3 (1+\epsilon)}{6}r^3\ge r^2 \log n^4.$$ That is,

$$r\ge \frac{24}{\log^3(1+\epsilon)} \log n.$$

So, taking

$$C= \frac{24}{\log^3(1+\epsilon)}$$ and 
$$r=C\log n= \frac{24}{\log^3(1+\epsilon)}\log n$$ then the inequality is satisfied $\forall n\in \mathbb{N}, \forall \epsilon >0.$

Comment: Sorry do you mean $C=f(\epsilon)=\mathrm{max}\{1,\frac{4}{\mathrm{log}(1+\epsilon)}\}$?

Comment: Fixed problems with notation in the answer.

Comment: Ok I have another problem with your solution $r\mathrm{log}(1+\epsilon) \geq 4\mathrm{log}(n)$ does not necessarily imply that $(1+\epsilon)^{r} \geq 4r^{2} \mathrm{log}(n)$.

Comment: In addition I'm sure you meant $r\mathrm{log}(1+\epsilon) \geq \mathrm{log}(4)+\mathrm{log}(\mathrm{log}(n))$

Comment: You are right. I have fixed some mistakes.

Comment: Any ideas on how large $n$ has to be here?

Comment: To give you an idea the assumption your working with $2log(r) \leq 1/2rlog(1+\epsilon)$ then taking $\epsilon=0.5$ and $r=log(n)$ we can set $n=100,000,000$ and it's still not satisfied.

Comment: I have edited the answer to give an explicit value of $C.$

Comment: Thanks!
Can you explain how you get $e^{rlog(1+\epsilon)} \geq (\mathrm{log}(1+\epsilon)/6)r^{3}$?

Comment: It's ok i missed the expansion you used

Comment: I have a quick question, the expansion you used for $e^{x}$, doesn't $x$ have to be within a certain radius of convergence? What if it is not?

Comment: No. The power series of the exponential function converges to $e^x$ for any $x\in\mathbb{R}.$